# Disabling and enabling select using angular

Tags: angular5

I want to disable and enable a select, using angular based on a condition.

```
  <select [disabled]="!isContinentSelected" class="form-control" formControlName="country">
      <option value="">Select Your Country</option>
      <option *ngFor="let country of countries" value="{{country.id}}">{{country.name}}</option>
 </select>
```

isContinentSelected returns true or false. But the is always enable even the condition is false. Im using Angular 5. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<select [attr.disabled]="isContinentSelected ? '': null" class="form-control" formControlName="country">
      <option value="">Select Your Country</option>
      <option *ngFor="let country of countries" value="{{country.id}}">{{country.name}}</option>
 </select>
```

Please try with this code.
This works in my case.